# New domain on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs app running on elastic beanstalk. I have a domain registered through GoDaddy and a cname that points to `myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

1. Can I point my domain to aws nameservers, instead of mapping that domain to the domain that eb has set up?

   This is how I would like to set up my domain, but when I attempted to, it wouldn't work (and I'm not sure why). I checked DNS propagation, and things looks good, but when browsing to my domain, things wouldn't work.
2. Can I set up subdomains to work with elastic beanstalk (eg. sub.example.com)?

   I read somewhere that subdomains cannot be set up in elastic beanstalk, but I don't understand why this would be. I'd like to have one app running at sellers.example.com and one at buyers.example.com. Can I do this with eb? If not, can I set this up on an ec2 instance and configure it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your end-goal can be achieved. In your case, you would create a CNAME of `sellers.example.com` pointing to `app1.elasticbeanstalk.com` and another CNAME of `buyers.example.com` pointing to `app2.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

You cannot point your domain to the Elastic Beanstalk name servers. You would use AWS Route53 DNS service and point your domain to those name servers. If you did this, you could create `sellers.example.com` and `buyers.example.com` as ALIAS records of your Elastic Beanstalk apps instead of CNAMEs. But if GoDaddy stays as your DNS host, then you'll have to stick with CNAME records.